# Solving a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation with trigonometric terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following ODE in $x\in[0,R]$:

$\frac{f''(x)x^2+f'(x)x + (x^2-1)\sin(f(x))\cos(f(x))}{x}=0 \quad$ and $f(0)=0$ and $f'(R)=0$.

I tried several stuff by hand but also asked Maple and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-%28f%27%27%28x%29%29*x%5E2-%28f%27%28x%29%29*x%2B%28-x%5E2%2B1%29*sin%28f%28x%29%29*cos%28f%28x%29%29%29%2Fx%3D0) but both of them do not give any answer.

I.e. I found out that the solution of
$f''(x)+\sin(f(x))\cos(f(x))=0 $ is $f(x)= \text{JacobiAM}(x/k,k)$ since $\frac{\partial^2 \text{JacobiAM}(x,k)}{\partial x^2} = -k^2\sin(f(x))\cos(f(x))$
where  $\text{JacobiAM}(x,k)$ is the Jacobi Amplitude Function  [Wikipedia/Jacobi_elliptic_functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions).

Furthermore, I obtained numerical solutions in terms of power series and Fourier series.
The qualitative form of the solutions are quite similar to a Jacobi Amplitude Function.

My question therefore is: Is it hopeless to find a closed form solution for this ODE?

I also thought about transforming the ODE using Fourier transforms.
If the transform is inside trigonometric function this does not really help or does it?

Do i miss i particular point or is this ODE really that problematic?

The function does not look very spectacular:

I solved f(x) with $R=2\sqrt{2}$ using a Power series approximation up to $x^6$ :

[image: f(x)]
($\rho$ is $x$)

I kindly ask to provide me a hint for a method which i also could try out to obtain e.g. a series solution or in terms of a transformation.